# Possible reasons for Andorid application being slower than windows (poor frame rate)

Tags: android, operating-system, performance

I have certain questions related to my application that does video decoding (written in C) and displays the decoded frame(I am using NDK):

1- On Android (running on 1 GHz Cortex A-8 processor) the application is running around 10 times slower than windows(running on 3 GHz processor). I am expecting 3-4 times slower but not 9-10 times slower.   (Basically frames are coming at very poor rate)

2- I thought I might not be compiling for correct target (Cortex A 8). So I edited my Application.mk file.

```
   APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips
```

Is there any other .mk file I have to edit?
Does this inclusion sufficient to believe that I am compiling for the correct target?
(Asking this since I am not getting any visible improvement even after including this. 
Is there a way I can be double sure that I am compiling for a correct target (Cortex A8).

**What can be possible reasons for getting such a huge difference in performance of Android and Windows, even though Android is a realtime O.S, Cortex is a dual issue processor, having Neon support etc.**

***Additional Info and my analysis:***

1-I must also mention that I am using main thread for updating the UI (calling Ondraw() ) and another thread for decoding.

2-After inserting some debug code, I can see that display function is called several times before a new frame is decoded. I am thinking that this might be the reason why I am getting poor frame rate; display is stealing all the CPU resources, so decoding is becoming slower and display function is displaying the same data again and again which is appearing as poor quality. In windows I am having single thread doing decoding and displaying, there is no main thread there. (Though this is my guess only I am not sure about the conclusion.)

Comment: Is there any difference between this question and your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10482757/1321873?

Comment: I did some experiments and now I am focusing on single thread (apart from main thread) as compared to 2 threads in the earlier case .  And also I have added more details to my question

Comment: you still measuring cpu "speed" in GHz?

Comment: No , I am interested in improving frame rate.

Comment: The possible reason is that you can't compare desktop and mobile processors. Hertz don't say anything, that's like comparing speed of a 90HP motorcycle with a 90HP truck. If you look at how much [FLOPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) a processor can do you get a better (but still not really comparable) result: [E8400@2x3Ghz](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=94721) ~20GFLOP, [Galaxy Nexus@2x1.2GHz](http://www.greenecomputing.com/apps/linpack/linpack-by-device/) ~80MFLOP -> Desktop CPU is 250 times faster.

Comment: Are you decoding all in software?  You should use the OS libraries or something that can directly use the hardware decode engine on the cortex A8 (assuming the video is in a format supported).  clock-for-clock mobile CPU's are orders of magnitude slower than desktop.